# Ensuring that ASP Session State is not used in my application

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-state

I am working on an ASP web app that used to use Session State. I want to remove ASP Session State from this application but I want to ensure that session state isn't still used anywhere in my project. I searched the project for "Session" and "TempData" and removed all references to those. Is there a comprehensive list of all ways a project might use session state so that I know I won't break anything?

Right now all I've done is set `<sessionState mode="Off" />` in my web config and tried to manually test everything in the project.

Comment: how are you hosting this site, IIS, krestel, apache?

Comment: We're using IIS to host the site

Comment: a few options off the top of my head: crawl your website and examine the cookies sent back to you by the web server, flagging any known session cookies like "ASP.NET_SessionId". crawl your website and examine the session with an IIS Handler. Or you could write a Unit Test that invokes each of your actions and asserts that the session is empty.